# Not able to fetch data from database while giving input to mongoose query through a href tag in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**This is my Schema**

```
const AutomationSchema=new mongoose.Schema(
  {EventName:String,
    EventDate:String,
     EventLocation:String,
     EventDetails:String
  }
)
```

**events model**

```
const EventsModel=new mongoose.model("Events",AutomationSchema)
```

**This is my express route
Although it is getting the right route param value in variable "eventName" and the record of "eventName" also exists in database but it is returning me a "null" in the **findOne query** ,But when I tried to put a string like  {EventName:"Sports"} e.g then it fetches the record correctly, Iam not able to figure out where did i do something wrong??**

```
app.get("/events/:EventName",function(req,res)
{ var eventName=req.params.EventName

  EventsModel.findOne({EventName:eventName},function(err,data)
  {
console.log(data)

  }

)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a chance for this to happen if there is whitespace on any side of the event name. Try removing the whitespace using the `trim` method before passing it to the query

```js
var eventName=req.params.EventName.trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your get request path is wrong.
try this   /events/myEventName  [do not put ':' before 'myEventName']

Comment: if a path is  localhost/:variableName   then :variableName will be your request parameter that's why Usman Haider put : there so the variable value will be able to access in the code.